# How to navigate on the button click in IOS?

Tags: mysql, xcode, ios6

I am new in iphone development.

I am creating simple login application with username and password.

After successful login i want to navigate UI to another UI.

Please suggest me how should I do this?

Comment: Welcome to SO, a place where we welcome questions to any programming related problems that you may have, however, we ask that you first show a genuine attempt towards the solution in which you seek as we will not just give out free code to those who do not try it first themselves. Happy coding! :)

Google Storyboard Segues.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using UINavigation Controller

```
[self.navigationController pushViewController:viewControllerObj animated:YES];
```

If you are Using storyBoard

```
[self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"identifier" sender:self];
```